# How to setup 'headers' cache context by value?

Tags: caching

I try to set a headers cache context (`/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/Context/HeadersCacheContext.php`) by the value of a custom HTTP header.

My web server sends a custom HTTP header `X-My-Custom-Header`. Its value can be `foo` or `bar`. I want to cache the page for both variants. As I understand the documentation right, that should work with Drupal's `headers` cache context.

I set the cache context in the preprocess hook:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(array &$variables) {
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'headers:X-My-Custom-Header';
}
```

The cache context is set correctly: `[headers:X-My-Custom-Header]=foo`

But if the value of the custom HTTP header changes to `bar`, the page is still loaded from cache. In my opinion Drupal should render the page and add it to the cache with context `[headers:X-My-Custom-Header]=bar`

How to set this up correctly?

Thanks for you suggestions or answers! :)

Comment: Just to confirm this is for authenticated users? If you've got the internal page cache enabled that will just cache the page the same for all anonymous users regardless of any contexts/tags

Comment: No, it is not for authenticated users. This should work for anonymous users. According to my expectation this should work the same way as e.g. cache context by url?!

Comment: Afraid not, by default Drupal assumes every anonymous user would receive the same output https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts#internal `Note the Internal Page Cache assumes that all pages served to anonymous users will be identical, regardless of the implementation of cache contexts. ` So if you'd like anonymous users to have differing output you'll need to disable the internal page caching on that page/whole site

Comment: Internal page cache varies on the URL anyway, so your preprocess will always be hit once per different URL. That's probably why it looks like URL-based contexts work for anon users. In reality, I think it's a different mechanism which controls it